# rhino javascript try catch scope during debug

Tags: javascript, rhino

I am currently using `rhyno javascript` library and I notice the following issue while using try catch blcok.

Below is my sample code.

```
function main() {
    var a =0;
    try {
        throw someException;

    } catch (exception) {
           var e = exception.name;
           var error = exception;
           return "Error is :"+error;

}
```

while debugging the code somehow the variable called **exception** declared inside catch is shown as *undefined*.But when I try to run the same code the exception is getting printed properly. Only issue I am seeing is while debugging the code.

Answer (score 0):

Rhino optimizes away the local variable `exception` when it is unreferenced. So in the debugger, it won't be defined unless you use it. The workaround I usually use is similar to the one you do:

```
try {
    doIt();
} catch (e) {
    var ex = e;
    // Now the value can be examined, because the assignment to a local variable causes the engine to require the variable in the scope
    debugger;
}
```

This sort of thing can happen in Chrome DevTools also, for example, when a variable is not actually accessed inside a scope.